# Set a environment variable and make it effective in all opened terminal

Tags: linux, shell, environment-variables

I have many opened terminals. Now I want to set a environment variable and wish the environment variable can effective in **all opened terminal(do'nt need lgout the shell and login again or any other extra command such as source to make it effective)** not just the terminal in which I set the environment variable.

Is there any ideas?

Comment: Write the environment variable to a file and `source` the file in all open terminals.  Or if you want the change to be *permanent*, add it your shell startup file (`${HOME}/.bashrc` if you're using `bash`) and then `source` it!

Comment: But I want find a solution that make it automatically .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the type of shell you use. For example, in bash, you can

1. create a file `~/.env` which will contain the settings.
2. in your `~/.bashrc`, tell each terminal to source the file at each prompt:

   ```
   PROMPT_COMMAND='. ~/.env'
   ```

If you change the `.env` file (e.g. try `echo TEST=1 > ~/.env`), then after pressing Enter in any terminal that uses the new `.bashrc`, `echo $TEST` will produce `1`.