# how to run a command in all open terminals without explicitly running it in each terminal individually

Tags: shell, terminal, alias

I often run into shortcuts that I'd like to update my ~/.alias file with and use immediately. The alias is not available to use in a terminal until I run source ~/.alias in that specific terminal. I have several open terminals and running "source ~/.alias" in each is time consuming. Is there any elegant way to do this?

I couldn't find a way to run a command in a different terminal from where it is executed. Other than when the terminal is created from an existing terminal.

This also applies to cases where you update the .zshrc. and would like to update all existing xterms automatically with it.

Comment: While I don’t know what OS you are using, if you are on Mac and open to other Terminal-like applications, I would suggest iTerm2. While I don’t use it, I know that it has functionality to do this.

Comment: See this answer posted 5-6 years ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18693093